# Baron Error with Pyomo: NonLinearity Error in POW expression

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to solve a nonlinear optimization problem in Pyomo with Baron. 
The solving works fine when using solvers like ipopt, bonmin, couenne etc.

When using Baron I get the following error:

```
===========================================================================
 BARON version 18.5.9. Built: WIN-64 Wed May 9 22:52:08 EDT 2018

BARON is a product of The Optimization Firm, LLC. http://www.minlp.com/
BARON: NonLinearity Error in POW expression
ERROR: Solver (baron) returned non-zero return code (9)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/public.THREADRIPPER/Desktop/CGAM_SWP.py", line 602, in <module>
    Results = opt.solve(comp, tee=True, keepfiles=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 626, in solve
    "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
pyutilib.common._exceptions.ApplicationError: Solver (baron) did not exit normally

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea where the problem is? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how urgent the matter still is but I experienced the same issue as you. Actually, in the BARON.py file there is a note regarding this error message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8leO.png) (hope you can see my screenshot, for some reason I am not allowed to upload pictures).
Anyway, I experience the problem in a different way than noted in the BARON.py file. In my case I am using the pyomo.core.base.symbolic.differentiate() function to create first derivates of functions which are to the power of (1/3) which then result in negative exponents which baron apparently has issues with. If I manually exchange the negative exponents with division, it seems to work.
Hope this helps you.

UPDATE: I have to update my comment because it is not negative exponents (per se) which in my case caused the error message of interest ("NonLinearity Error in POW expression", Solver (baron) returned non-zero return code (9)) but it is the way I had introduced them in the input file. In the baron manual there is an example of the case ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGXy1.png)) I am referring to. 
So in my case the error message was caused because I had constraints defined like this:
... * ( -241.5 + 0.5 * x12 ) ^ -1.0  *  ( x1 - x6 ) ^ -1.0  *  ( -483.0 + x12 + x1 - x6 ) ^ -1.0 * ...
which are according to the baron manual misinterpreted by the solver compared to my intention. Actually, in my case a x^y situation was created with nested negative exponential expressions which probably could be solved by baron if it is introduced differently ([see next screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFA0t.png)). However, if I include parentheses around the exponents, to get the expressions I am aiming for, i.e.:
... * ( -241.5 + 0.5 * x12 ) ^ (-1.0)  *  ( x1 - x6 ) ^ (-1.0)  *  ( -483.0 + x12 + x1 - x6 ) ^ (-1.0) * ...
it works perfectly fine.